# Xamarin: Cant register for location updates. "Specified cast not valid"

Tags: xamarin, gps

so i was working on an app, that would simply give your coordinates back to the user. This worked fine as long as I had it in my main activity. 
Now i changed all of this into its own class. Now, when I start this class the first thing that happens is this line of code:

```
public void StartLocationUpdates()
{
    _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
}
```

This SHOULD now have my phone start to listen for location updates. But when i call this line, I get:

System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Why is this happening?
Also, Do I even need this code? Because the method "InitializeLocationManager()" should do this for me, right?

Thanks :)

Comment: have you checked the docs to see if the arguments you are passing match the signature of the method call?

Comment: yes i did. i got everything from the tutorial. yet it crashes :(

Comment: which tutorial are you following?

Comment: its from the offical xamarin guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

Comment: did you read the big red note that says "this recipe is deprecated"?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same last week. Remove the app and all debug related Xamarin stuff like 'Mono Shared Runtime' and 'Xamarin.Android API-x Support' from the emulator or device. After that clean and rebuild the project. With a fresh deploy it should work again. At least it did for me.

Comment: hey thanks! ill give it a try soon!
but am i right first intializing the location manager and after registering for location updates? or is this happening automatically and i dont have to call the registering function at all?

Comment: okay i just tryed what u said. though i dont now what this mono shared runtime and xamarin.android api-x support is? i did clean everything up and rebuild it. yet i get the same error :(

Comment: If you build your app with the Debug build configuration then Xamarin installs those two app too to minimize build times. Go to the settings app on your device or emulator and select apps. After that you get a list of installed apps. Make sure you select "All apps". Scroll through that list and you should see both.

Comment: hi again and thanks!!
unfotuantely, that also didnt do the trick. I think i might be having trouble understanding how the gps on my phone works. to clearfy this a little better, i made this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470546/xamarin-cant-register-for-location-updates-on-android-cast-not-valid
if you could please check that one out too, maybe this will lighten us all up a little. and thank u much already for taking the time :)

Answer (score 0):

I ahd the same error today and found the solution: make sure the service you're passing to

```
_locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 0, 0, this);
```

as the last arguments inherits from Java.Lang.Object, like:

```
public class GpsService : Java.Lang.Object, ILocationListener
{
    ...
}
```